# Which chems are addictive?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Specifically, I'm wondering about Turbo, Cateye and Hydra. Are any of them addictive? If so, what's the chance of getting addicted?

I've been holding onto these chems, but selling the ones I'm used to (Buffout, Med-X, Psycho, etc.), in case they could be useful without "hooking" me. Am I misguided? If so, am I misguided because (if I want to avoid addiction) I should sell them, or am I misguided because (if they're not addictive) I should be using them when needed?

Comment: Weed...oh wait, this is about games

Comment: Weed isn't [physically] addictive, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This data is taken directly from the GECK.

```
Chem        Add. chance    Add. effect
--------------------------------------
Hydra       10%            EN -3
Cateye      -              -
Turbo       20%            AG -2
Buffout     10%            EN -1 ST -1
Jet         20%            AG -1 CH -1
Mentats     5%             PE -1 IN -1
Psycho      10%            EN -1 PE -1
Steady      80%            AG -1 ST -1
```